# KerberosKey in Swift

Tags: java, ios, swift

There is a login api which authenticate user having userid & password as param , which is in java.I am supposed to send the param as a cipher text using des algorithm.The problem is on backend they are doing encryption using the KerberosKey generator

```
KerberosPrincipal KerPr = new KerberosPrincipal("****");

public KerberosKey(KerberosPrincipal principal,
       char[] password,
       String algorithm)
```

All the things provided by java "javax.security.auth.kerberos".How can I achieve the same in iOS.